# Is there a way to automatically load an entire page on youtube playlists?

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

Im having an issue where the playlist that im viewing is so long that when i scroll down it takes a significant time to propagate the next load of videos on youtube.

Is there a way to just load everything all at once?

I am using google chrome.

Comment: Is there any reason for not using YouTube Data API v3 [PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) endpoint ?

Comment: Instead of "scrolling down" you can use "End" key on your keyboard, if you haven't yet. It's still taking excessive time but it's a bit faster, and requires no coding.